# Can my Timeline statuses be copied/transferred to my Facebook group?

Tags: facebook

I've been posting and sharing awesome posts on my Timeline and I have this group on Facebook which would be very interesting if all of the Timeline statuses got transfered (copied) to that group.

Can this be done?

Comment: Maybe it can be done with a service that will automate it, such as IFTTT or Zapier